# I need to control the vertical Spacing between DIVs?

Tags: css, margin, space, between

This is my CSS, and yes it is in a table, which I assume is a big no no…

You can see the examples at:

http://jsfiddle.net/pb7808do/2/

```
}
div#titlediv {
    left: 0px;
    background: #FFF;
    font - size: 52px;
    font - family:'Open Sans', sans - serif;
    font - weight: 800;
    line - height: 50px;
    margin: 0px 0px - 30px 0px;
    padding: 0;
    color: #ec832e;
}
div#bodydiv {
    left: 0px;
    background: #FFF;
    top: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font - size: 20px;
    font - family:'Open Sans', sans - serif;
    font - weight: 300;
    margin - top: -20px 0px 0px 0px;
    line - height: 170 %;
    color: #828486;
}
```

http://philpadilla.com/PPGD2/index_portfolio_inside.html

I have tried:

```
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px 0px -XXpx 0px;
```

Out of ideas... What property can I add to my CSS to eliminate the gap displayed?
Or what I can do structurally different to eliminate this issue?

Comment: Also, I'm thinking, based on your screenshot, the `div` isn't your issue, but rather the inherit `line-height` and `margin` on a header tag.

Comment: It's almost imposible to guess what is in your mind and how can we help you. Please formulate your question more accurately, giving specific details about the issue and what would you like to do as well as the code that you are using.

Comment: Hi, the code is at: http://philpadilla.com/PPGD2/phils_CSS_problem.jpg

Comment: code posted: http://jsfiddle.net/pb7808do/

Comment: Hey, @PhilP. Folks here want to help you out, but we're operating, still, on not enough information. The jsfiddle you posted has styles but no markup. Your title claims the issue is between divs, and your description claims there are tables. Most of us CSS guys could probably nail this right away if you'd just put everything up in your fiddle. As an aside, SO prefers you post your code somewhere slightly more permanent than a personal website. I highly recommend that everything live either in your question description or jsfiddle. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you @kbrimington, css and html besides basic tables is very new to me, I appreciate your help and apologize if my questions appear rookie. In fact they are very rookie.. I have added the entire html with css at this link: http://jsfiddle.net/pb7808do/

Comment: Ergh.... try again. http://jsfiddle.net/pb7808do/2/

Comment: kbrimington Help please oh please?

Comment: kbrimington Live links: http://jsfiddle.net/pb7808do/2/

http://philpadilla.com/PPGD2/index_portfolio_inside.html

Comment: margin-top: 0px 0px 0px 0px; I was kicking myself why the css was not overriding the html margins...? the -top portion was screwing me. Once revised to margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; everything snapped back to normal. Yay, this site is legit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the `line-height:170%`; and it should work.

Comment: I can remove the line-height: 170%; and it changes the leading between lines but does not effect the gap between the two DIVs